# Многократный рендер компонента VUE

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Есть обычный vuetify табы в которых по нажатию таба рендерится компонент, но вот проблема в том что при какой то не ведомой мне причине при нажатии на все табы один компонент будет рендерится столько раз сколько и табов(((

App.js

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <v-sheet elevation="0" style="max-width: 700px">
          <v-tabs
            v-model="tab"
            next-icon="mdi-arrow-right-bold-box-outline"
            prev-icon="mdi-arrow-left-bold-box-outline"
            show-arrows
          >
            <v-tabs-slider></v-tabs-slider>
            <v-tab
              v-for="item in items"
              :key="item.title"
              @click="currentTabComponent = item.routeName"
            >
              {{ item.title }}
            </v-tab>
          </v-tabs>
        </v-sheet>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <v-tabs-items v-model="tab" class="test">
          <v-tab-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.title">
            <v-card color="basil" flat>
              <v-card-text>
                <component v-bind:is="currentTabComponent"></component>
              </v-card-text>
            </v-card>
          </v-tab-item>
        </v-tabs-items>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import one from "./One";
import two from "./Two";
import tree from "./Tree";
import four from "./Four";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    one,
    two,
    tree,
    four
  },
  data: () => ({
    currentTabComponent: "one",
    tab: null,
    items: [
      {
        routeName: "one",
        title: "1111",
      },
      {
        routeName: "two",
        title: "222",
      },
      {
        routeName: "tree",
        title: "333",
      },
      {
        routeName: "four",
        title: "444",
      },
    ],
  }),
};
</script>
```

Любой из этих компонентов:

```
<template>
  <div>
    Four
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Four',
  created() {
    this.init();
  },
  methods: {
    init() {
      console.log('Four');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

В консоле:

```
One
Two.vue?bffe:14 Two
Two.vue?bffe:14 Two
(2)Four.vue?8941:14 Four
Four.vue?8941:14 Four
(3)Tree.vue?8774:14 Tree
Tree.vue?8774:14 Tree
(4)Two.vue?bffe:14 Two
(4)One.vue?79da:14 One
(4)Four.vue?8941:14 Four
(4)Tree.vue?8774:14 Tree
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что vuetify постоянно перебирает все компоненты и рисует их все(((
Всю надстройку v-tabs-items можно убирать и оставить только

```
<component v-bind:is="currentTabComponent"></component>
```